# Error: 'An error occurred while establishing connection to remote data source'

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure SQL Databases.

I'm trying to create an external data source for a database 1 to a database 2 in the same server, so both the databases are located on the same server. After creating the external data source for the database 1 I create an external table in database 1 that have the same definition as a table that exist in database 2. After creating the table I run the following query on database 1:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SomeTableName]
```

The query results in an error with the following message

> Msg 46832, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> An error occurred while establishing connection to remote data source: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '[credential_identity used to create db scoped cred]'.[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '[credential_identity used to create db scoped cred]'.

It seems like a credential issue at first glance, but, to clarify on that, all databases on the server use the same credentials to access them.

The db scoped credential that I used, was one that was already available for me to use and the credential_id seems to be the correct one as it is the same one I use to access all of the databases. I did not create the scoped credential, I just use one that was created by another person for the same purpose, but, to connect to a different db. The query I used to create the external data source is the following:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <database 2> WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = '<database 2>',
    CREDENTIAL = <scoped_credential>,
) ;
```

And after that I created an external table that uses the external data source created with the following query:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[someTableName]
( 
<... respective definitions>
)
WITH
( DATA_SOURCE = MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc)
```

This seems to be like an obvious error, I think I would probably have to create a new scoped credential, but right now I'm trying to solve the issue on my own, and trying this implies asking for permission from supervisor and following defined processes for the matter. Just trying to expose my problem to the public to see if I'm missing something important. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error when I tried to reproduce but after checking it was because of **wrong credentials**.

> Msg 46832, Level 16, State 3, Line 31
> An error occurred while establishing connection to remote data source: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username.[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'.

[image]

```sql
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='pratik@2961';

-- enter credetials to login to Azure SQL Database
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL mycred12
WITH 
    IDENTITY = 'username', 
    SECRET = 'password';

-- CREATE EXTERNAL DATASOURCE
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE mydatasource1 WITH
(
    TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = N'your_servername.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = N'databasename',
    CREDENTIAL = mycred12
)


-- CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AzureDBtable1234
(
AirlineCode nvarchar(MAX),
Name nvarchar(MAX),
Date nvarchar(MAX)
) -- must ensure data structure matches the one on SQL Database
WITH(
    DATA_SOURCE = mydatasource12,
    SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo',
    OBJECT_NAME = 'Airlines'
)

SELECT * FROM AzureDBtable1234
```

***OUTPUT***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue

I resloved the issue by altering the DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL

Note: Make sure your DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL **IDENTITY** && **SECRET** Should match with your server admin Username and password.

currently elastic query only supports sql server authentication

Example: Server name: dev0001.database.windows.net

```
     sql server authentication: username: sqladmin
                                password: acd67@hu*3
```

Then you need to use this query

```
   -- CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL
  CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL sqlcross
  WITH IDENTITY = 'sqladmin',
  SECRET = 'acd67@hu*3';
  GO

  --CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE
  CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [MyElasticQueryDataSrc] 
  WITH (
  TYPE = RDBMS,
  LOCATION = N'dev0001.database.windows.net',
  DATABASE_NAME = N'devstg',
  CREDENTIAL = sqlcross)
  GO
```